# Write a script that reads a number and counts down to 0?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have to write a script that reads a number and counts it down to 0.

I keep getting this error:

```
practice123.sh: line 10: let: 1=[: attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=[")
```

I can't seem to get the loop to count down properly. I'm using shell check, and my syntax seems fine. Any input would be appreciated.

```
#!bin/bash
# This script will take one number from the CLI and see if the argument  given is a valid variable. Then it will count that variable down to 0.

var1=var1
echo "Enter a number."
read var1
until [ "$var1" -le 0 ]
do
    echo "$var1"
    let $var1=[ $var1 -1 ]
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic expressions use double parentheses, not square brackets:

```
(( var1 = var1 - 1 ))
```

or shorter

```
(( var1 -= 1 ))
(( var1-- ))
(( --var1 ))
```

You can use `let`, as well:

```
let var1=var1-1
let var1--
let --var1
let 'var1 = var1 - 1'  # Quotes needed for whitespace.
```

You can also use arithmetic expansion (but why?)

```
var1=$(( var1 - 1 ))
```

Answer (score -3):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# linux countdown script
echo "countdown loading....."
sleep 2
echo "Enter value below"
read number
countdown=$number
until [ $countdown -le "0" ];
do
    echo "$countdown"
    (( countdown -= 1 ))
    if [ $countdown ];
    then
        sleep 1
    fi
done
    echo "countdown completed"
```

Comment: Hello unclepeeh. Please format your code using the `{}` button. An explanation would be useful so that others can benefit from your suggestion